# Getting error in building project in using bower, nodejs, grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have created project using nodejs,

bower packages are installed but not added the  tags in index.html, so I have manually inserted the script tags like ../bower_components

so I am getting this error

```
http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2016-05-24 18:11:04.419 http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2016-05-24 18:11:04.581 angular.js:4587 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bulbulPortal20App due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

to avoid these errors in future what I have to do?

Comment: Use relative URLs to include bower components. `../bower_components/...` or the dependencies are not injected in the app.

Comment: This might help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541077/multiple-image-upload-using-node-js/34542249#34542249

Comment: hello kavya, how it is helpful? can you please explain

Comment: pls show your server.js(main app file) code, you need to add a pthe there.

Comment: I dont have access to server.js, and what is the relation for server.js and index.html bower components